# Does Homebrew require a `lib` symlink in my home directory?

Tags: homebrew

My Mac seems to have a `lib` symlink, pointing to `/opt/homebrew/lib` in my home directory. Is this required? I'd like to delete it if not.

I suspect it's not standard and I may have made it myself in the past - but I can't remember a reason...

```
jamie@Jamies-Air ~> ls -al lib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jamie  staff  17 Apr 21 12:10 lib@ -> /opt/homebrew/lib
```